# Control which lines have points?

Tags: javascript, chart.js

With Chart.js, you can set in the options of the graph to show points or not:

```
pointDot: true,
```

I have a graph with three static lines and one line that shows some fluctuations.  I'd like the straight lines not to have points but the fluctuation line show the points.  Is there a setting somewhere on the line that I can set the point size to nothing?

** Edit **

Each line is its own set of data configured like this:

```
 datasets: [
    {
        label: "Cycle Time Per Last Piece",
        strokeColor: "red",
        fillColor: "red",
        pointHighlightFill: "red",
        data: [@foreach (var item in Model.DataPoints) {
        @(Model.ExpectedCycleTimePerPart * 1.20M)@:,
             }]
    },
    {
        label: "Expected Cycle Time Per Part",
        strokeColor: "black",
        pointHighlightFill: "black",
        data: [@foreach (var item in Model.DataPoints) {
        @Model.ExpectedCycleTimePerPart@:,
             }]
     }
```

Comment: Are these *lines* individual series ? If so can these individual series be configured? I'm not familiar with `Chart.js` though!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `pointDot` option drives the `display` property, so you can do something like

```
myChart.datasets[0].points[2].display = false;
```

where myChart is your chart object.