# Drawing line chart in chart.js placing dots only when value changes

Tags: javascript, charts, chart.js

I am using a chart in my page using chart.js I have on my x axis dates while on my y axis values(cost). I want to keep the line chart continue its value until there is a change and have coded for that. Here is the output

[image]

In this as marked if the value is same I have dots plotted. I have an option to remove all dots but I want to remove dots if the value is same as previous.(there is no change). I would like to know if this is doable. If please guide me how to go for it?

**Its not the same as marked for being duplicate...**
I want them to be true or flse based on value. If value is zero or same as previous then dont display dot

**HERE IS MY CODE**

```
as.dashboard = {};

as.dashboard.adjustWidgetsHeight = function () {
    var maxHeight = 0;
    $(".panel-widget .panel-heading").height('auto');
    $(".panel-widget .panel-heading").each(function () {
        if ($(this).height() > maxHeight) {
            maxHeight = $(this).height();
        }
    });
    $(".panel-widget .panel-heading").height(maxHeight);
};

as.dashboard.initChart = function () {
    var data = {
        labels: dayss,


        //Number - Tension of the bezier curve between points
        bezierCurveTension : 0.4,

        datasets: [
            {
                label: "Machine costs History",
                fillColor: "rgba(151,187,205,0.2)",
                strokeColor: "rgba(151,187,205,1)",
                pointColor: "rgba(151,187,205,1)",
                pointStrokeColor: "#fff",
                pointHighlightFill: "#fff",
                pointHighlightStroke: "rgba(151,187,205,1)",
                bezierCurve : false,
                data: costVariations
            }
            , {
                label: "My third dataset", // This ONE IS DUMMY IT HELPS IN 
                                           // SOLVING OVERLAPPING TOOL TIPS
            }
        ]
    };

    var ctx = document.getElementById("myChart").getContext("2d");
    var myLineChart = new Chart(ctx).Line(data, {
        responsive: true,
        maintainAspectRatio: false,
        tooltipTemplate: "<%if (value!=0){%><%= value %> <%= units %> <%}%>",
        multiTooltipTemplate: "<%if (value!=0){%><%= value %> <%= units %> <%}%>",
    });
};

$(document).ready(function () {

    as.dashboard.adjustWidgetsHeight();
    as.dashboard.initChart();
});
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Control which lines have points?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35919313/control-which-lines-have-points)

Comment: I want them to be true or flse based on value. If value is zero or same as previous then dont display dot

Comment: You can just loop through your input data and hide the points if the values are equals, something like `for (var i = 1; i <= data.datasets[0].data.length - 1; i++) if (data.datasets[0].data[i - 1] === data.datasets[0].data[i] myChart.datasets[0].points[2].display = false;` - I might have made some mistakes in the indices, but you pretty much get the idea...

Comment: I thought of it but then i would be missing the days in x axis. and hence it won't display the periods where the price was fixed appropriately. As in attached image. we have a long period where the price is arround 33 it should show that in the graph!

Comment: `display = false` just doesn't show the point "as a dot" on the line, the point will still take up space on the graph - give it a shot. Or better still, give it a shot and if it doesn't work include the fiddle in the question. Cheers!

Comment: @potatopeelings can you please help me out where to put this code? When I use it I am getting errors.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

```
...
for (var i = 1; i <= data.datasets[0].data.length - 1; i++) 
    if (data.datasets[0].data[i - 1] === data.datasets[0].data[i])
        myChart.datasets[0].points[i].display = false;
```

where myChart is your chart object

---

Fiddle - http://jsfiddle.net/3tok57dL/

Comment: can we disable tooltip as well on such values?

Comment: just override showTooltip to splice out the above points. See http://jsfiddle.net/3tok57dL/2/